# Changing GameState based on an if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, nested, collision

I'll get to the point. Having an issue with a beginner level game im coding at the moment. I have 2 lists to store "Objects" that are in the game. One is for "diamonds" pushable blocks that are to be moved onto the "Goals". Once all diamonds are on the goals, the level should change. I'm currently using "GameStates" to load each level. Here is the snippet of my code I'm having issues with. What happens currently is the game will allow me to push the "diamonds" onto the "goals", but the gamestate will not change once I do this. Not sure what I am missing - any help is appreciated. Thankyou for your time!

```
void Level1Update(KeyboardState cKB, KeyboardState oKB)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < diamondlist.Count; i++)
            {
                if ((Goallist[i].Position == diamondlist[i].Position))
                {
                    CurrentGameState = GameState.Level2;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: A potential problem I see is in your if condition, are you sure that the diamond position will exactly be equal to the goal position? Describing the game a bit more would help.

Comment: The map is basically a 16x16 tile layout. The play can move N, S E, or W by one tile. When the player collides with a diamond, the diamond will move one tile space in the corresponding direction. As it stands, the "Goal" is also in a tile. My goal is to make it so that once the diamonds are on the same tiles as the goals, the next gamestate should load - if that makes sense?

Comment: Why does the loop start at i=2? And do you know that Goal[i] will be covered by Diamond[i], or could any diamond go onto any goal?

Comment: Um, each "map" is loaded onto a different game state. With only a set amount of diamonds spawning on each "state" if you will. I thought that if i didn't make the loop for only the first level and controlling only the 2 diamonds which spawn on that level then it wouldn't work? Technically any diamond should be able to go into any goal, then once all of the goals are covered the gamestate should change - that make sense? :/ - sorry as I said, still relatively new to this.

Comment: update: changed i = 0 - rookie mistake haha. Now I have the GameState changing once one of the diamonds is in position. But I need the game to wait until all diamonds on the state are in position :S

Comment: Craig, instead of changing the CurrentGameState inside the if clause, try counting how many diamonds were inside their goals.  After the end of the for loop, check if that number is equal to the number of diamonds.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to set current game state to the next level only if all the diamonds and goals are on the same tiles. The following code ensures that.

```
void Level1Update(KeyboardState cKB, KeyboardState oKB)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < diamondlist.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (Goallist[i].Position != diamondlist[i].Position)
            break;
    }
    // When breaked off the loop, i is never equal to list count
    if (i == diamondList.Count)
        CurrentGameState = GameState.Level2;
}
```